# macro guardar y cerrar multiples excel abiertos

Tags: excel, vba

Si alguien puede decirme como guardar y cerrar múltiples excel abiertos desde un excel con macro

```
Sub SaveAll()   
    Dim Wkb As Workbook
    For Each Wkb In Workbooks
        If Not Wkb.ReadOnly And Windows(Wkb.Name).Visible Then
            Wkb.Save
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

ese código no guarda los datos editados en sus respectivos excel y se buggea los archivos.

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza algo así en archivo PERSONAL.XLSB para que este disponible en todos los archivos:

```
Sub SaveAll()
    Dim Wkb As Workbook
    For Each Wkb In Workbooks
        If Wkb.Name <> ActiveWorkbook.Name 
            If Wkb.ReadOnly = False Then
                Wkb.Close SaveChanges:=True
            Else
                Wkb.Close SaveChanges:=False
            End If
        End If
    Next Wkb
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Están mal las comillas.

Comment: Es cierto, ya lo corregí, gracias